# updating a statement in SQL throwing error

Tags: sql-server

```
 update t1
set t1.Act_flg='N'
from STG_EmployeeMaster t1
where t1.GPN NOT IN (#Temp_EmployeeMaster.GPN) t2
```

Getting an error: Incorrect syntax near 't2'.

Comment: How do i tag the temp table as t2?

Comment: You need to select something in your subquery

Comment: Nor do you need to tag it with an alias, you aren't using any of the fields.

Comment: I added something like this: `update t1
set t1.Act_flg='N'
from STG_EmployeeMaster t1,  #Temp_EmployeeMaster t2
where t1.GPN NOT IN (t2.GPN)`

but it ended up all the records instead of only the ones that dont exist in other table

Answer (score 1):

```
update t1
set t1.Act_flg='N'
from STG_EmployeeMaster t1
where t1.GPN NOT IN (select GPN from #Temp_EmployeeMaster)
```